# Qt C++ compiling is done without the program showing

Tags: c++, qt

So I build a Qt simple application, the program is crashing before you see a Window and here is the code:

First.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-03-31T18:48:54
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = First
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("Pushed!"); // Just this

}
```

Whenever I click the run button left down side, it compiles successfully but I don't see anything is there any problem? I am using "*Qt 5.6.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2, 1.0 GB)*" by the way.

Comment: Although it's not necessarily a "proper" solution, try adding `ui->label->repaint();` immediately after just to help debug a little. Also put a `qDebug` / breakpoint in there to make sure the member function is actually getting called.

Comment: Hi there OMGtechy, where should I put qDebug exactly? How to implement that exactly?

Comment: `qDebug() << "TEST";`- if you can get error saying it's undefined or something make sure you include the `QDebug` header. More info can be found here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html

Comment: Okay this was from the application output: Starting *C:\Users\Fur\Documents\Programming\build-First-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\First.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\Fur\Documents\Programming\build-First-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\First.exe crashed*

Comment: This one is from Compile Output: *17:59:39: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
17:59:39: Elapsed time: 00:03.*

Comment: Your code isn't even executing - the program is crashing before you see a Window. Please add this information to the question so other people can see it more easily. You should launch it in debug mode to see where it's crashing (it's the play icon with a bug next to it in Qt Creator). Then you should update your question with your findings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107837/discussion-between-fur-and-omgtechy).

Comment: One quick question, you do have a main function executing the application right?

Comment: Yes Tim Smit, I am just showing the mainwindow.cpp code.

Comment: Run it under a Debugger and check where it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my problem is that, you have to copy the all the .dll files from the directory: **C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\mingw49_32\bin** to your build folder. In my case it is: **C:\Users\Fur\Documents\Programming\build-First-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit-Release\release** Yes I am using release profile because higher performance and does not eat resources much than Debug. After you copied all the .dll files just clean it up by deleting all .dll files from that build folder(make sure that your executable is running while doings this). This is to clean up your build folder and the needed .dll files will stay ;)

Comment: you may also check the Options of Build & Run if everything is setup correctly there(to be able to run from QtCreator).. very tricky to delete dlls while running the app  :)

Comment: Yep because it will argue that the dll is being used by the running app hahaha, kinda tricky yes. Because using all of those .dll files is really heavy in your drive like 1GB+ :O

Comment: yes this trick will work unless there are no plugins involved (which are loaded ondemand at runtime I guess), but again if they are already loaded then this trick will work properly